# Can't access Fragment views after activity recreates

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, view

Guys I am stuck in very strange issue with fragments. Tomorrow morning is my release I am have no idea how to get through this issue.  Let me explain you my issue. 
I am displaying fullscreen fragment in an activity. Every thing is working good except one. When I press **back button** to kill the app and relaunch it ( app is still in recent ) then I am not able to access my view. Like I can't change their visibility. Views are not even null but still I can't access them.
When I restart the app after removing it from recent apps, everything works fine.. This is really strange. My manager is this close to beat me up.
How I am placing the fragments is shown in below code.

```
 mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            Fragment oldFragment = mFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainer);
            if (oldFragment != null) {
                fragmentTransaction.remove(oldFragment).commit();
            }
            fragmentTransaction
                    .replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, new HomeFragment(), Constants.MAIN_FRAME_FRAGMENT)
//                         .addToBackStack(Constants.MAIN_FRAME_FRAGMENT)
                    .commit();
            // mFragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
        }
```

Comment: please share your code

Comment: How I am placing the fragments is shown in the code.

Comment: If your oldFragment == null, can you try findFragmentByTag(Constants.MAIN_FRAME_FRAGMENT) ?

Comment: I tried that also. Didn't work out